# Remove duplicate and clean line break / blank space in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-formatting

This is my problem;

```
one two      three             four    four   five  five   six
   seven            eight
```

And I can't figure it out how to format it like this;

```
one two three four five six seven eight
```

Any help - thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\s+`
- Replace with:    # a single space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\s+     # 1 or more spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]